# Feeding Python utf-8 strings to Scala

Tags: python, scala, unicode

I am passing strings generated in Python to Scala programs using subprocess.

(here cli of [rockymadden's Stringmetric](https://rockymadden.com/stringmetric/) package)

One of the problematic strings is

```
"thomasholgerhst\xfctzlehoos"
```

Is there a way to format unicode strings in Python such that they become readily accepted by Scala?

P.S. I am yet to write programs in Scala.

Comment: How are you reading them? You should be able to specify the encoding of the string when Scala reads it if you're getting it from a file on disk.

Comment: @KChaloux The strings are loaded into a Python dictionary first which are then sent to Scala cli via subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

To declare unicode strings in python, prefix the string literal with a u. So instead of `"thomasholgerhst\xfctzlehoos"` use `u"mystringliteral"`. Then to convert a unicode string to utf-8 use `.encode("utf-8")`.

```
u"mystringliteral".encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: I use unicode(str_1, "utf-8") before feeding the string into the Scala program.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your code to mark all string literals as utf-8 encoded.